# How to get activity context in recyclerview adapter using dagger 2.26?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger-2

How to get activity context in recyclerview adapter using dagger 2.26? I am only able to fetch the application context as I have created the applicationContextModule. I am using the activityBuilderModule to inject the dependencies in the activity. But how to inject the Only activity related context in the adapter?

One can refer to the code here on my github repo: https://github.com/DevAnuragGarg/MovieBox

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but I imagine you need the activity context to be able to start an activity from the adapter, right?

Maybe consider using a "click listener" interface and pass into the adapter instead, and then have the implementation in the fragment or activity containing the adapter. E.g https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

You can then use Dagger to bind the interface to the activity in a dagger module close to your activity.

It feels cleaner than passing direct references to activity, more aligned with the SRP & reduces logic in the adapter.

Comment: you should also be aware that injecting adapters into the activity may cause leaks if you don't "clean up" well. See: https://medium.com/@yfujiki/tracing-simple-memory-leak-around-recyclerview-using-leakcanary-927460532d53